# int class constructor accepts bytes, or bytearray instance?

Tags: python, constructor, integer

*I am learning Python and I'm little confused about the int class constructor*

**Does the int class constructor accept bytes, or bytearray instance?**

---

**From the doc:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

```
class int([x])
class int(x, base=10)
```

If `x` is not a number or if base is given, then `x` must be a string, **bytes, or bytearray instance** representing an integer literal in radix base.

---

If I pass the bytes instance, then I am getting the below error.

```
i = 10
b = bytes(i)

val = int(b)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    val = int(b)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That refers to bytes of text:

```py
>>> int(b'123')
123
```

You seem to be looking for [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).